# Oracle SQL Group By Upper

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 database tables, which I want to use in my SQL Query:

The issue is, I want to do `GROUP BY` on a "School name" value found in the MYMAINSCHEMA.SURVEY table. However, the "School Name" can sometimes be upper case or lower case.

Here is my SQL:

```
select SR.SCHOOL_NUM,UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME), COUNT(S.SWSID) AS NUMSTUDENTS 
from MYMAINSCHEMA.SURVEY S 
JOIN MYOTHERSCHEMA.SCHOOL_RTO SR ON S.SCHOOLCODE = SR.SCHOOL_NUM
JOIN  MYOTHERSCHEMA.RTO R ON R.RTO_NUM = SR.RTO_NUM 
GROUP BY SR.SCHOOL_NUM,UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)
ORDER BY S.SCHOOLNAME ASC;
```

Running the above gives me the error "not a GROUP BY expression".
If I remove the `UPPER` in the 1st and 2nd last line, it works OK, but the result returns duplicate SCHOOL names (some in upper case, some in lower case).

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select SR.SCHOOL_NUM,
  UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME) SCHOOLNAME, -- added alias here
  COUNT(S.SWSID) AS NUMSTUDENTS 
from MYMAINSCHEMA.SURVEY S 
JOIN MYOTHERSCHEMA.SCHOOL_RTO SR ON S.SCHOOLCODE = SR.SCHOOL_NUM
JOIN  MYOTHERSCHEMA.RTO R ON R.RTO_NUM = SR.RTO_NUM 
GROUP BY SR.SCHOOL_NUM,UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)
ORDER BY SCHOOLNAME ASC;  -- fixed here by sorting on the alias
                          -- (can use "UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)")
```

The `UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)` is used in the aggregation. So, `S.SCHOOLNAME` is not available for ordering. Either use `UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)`, it's alias or column number.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the ORDER BY which was causing the problem. I was thrown off by the "not a GROUP BY expression" error message, which hinted that something was wrong with my GROUP BY, rater than the ORDER by.

Comment: In situations like above ,Oracle also allows to specify column number in the `ORDER BY` clause. `ORDER BY 2 ASC` is perfectly acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The issues is the `ORDER BY`.  Just use the `UPPER()` there too:

```
ORDER BY UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME) ASC;
```

If I assume that `school_num` is actually unique, then I might suggest:

```
select SR.SCHOOL_NUM, MAX(UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)),
        COUNT(S.SWSID) AS NUMSTUDENTS 
from MYMAINSCHEMA.SURVEY S join
     MYOTHERSCHEMA.SCHOOL_RTO SR 
     on S.SCHOOLCODE = SR.SCHOOL_NUM join
     MYOTHERSCHEMA.RTO R 
     on R.RTO_NUM = SR.RTO_NUM 
group by SR.SCHOOL_NUM
order by MAX(UPPER(S.SCHOOLNAME)) ASC;
```